# Connection between linkinfo.dll and error (0xc000007b)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, dependencies

Does it possible exe file give an error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application" because of linkinfo.dll??

I have tried this exe file at first PC and gave good condition. But when i tried at second PC, it gave an error. I used Dependency Walker to check my exe file. In first PC, my exe file still connected with linkinfo.dll. But in my second PC was not..

If it was possible, How can i fix it??
This is my exe file condition in my first PC.

[image]

This is my exe file condition in my second PC.
[image]